# laravel soft delete using a form

Tags: laravel, eloquent, soft-delete

Hi I am trying to soft delete and restore a user using a form, I am using a couple of packages for user auth and roles which are [Zizaco Confide](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) and [Zizaco Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust). I've added the following to the user.php model

```
use SoftDeletingTrait;
use ConfideUser;
use HasRole;
protected $softDelete = true;
```

and I've run a test as so to test this works:

```
Route::get('/deleteme', function(){ 
    User::find(2)->delete();
    return 'done';
});
```

and this updated the timestamp field, however I want to put this into my controller to neaten things up and give it a form. So I've done this in the table of users:

```
 @if(empty($user->deleted_at))
           {{Form::open(['method'=>'PATCH','action'=>
            ['UsersController@softDeleteUser',$user->id]])}}
              <button type="submit">Suspend</button>
              {{Form::close()}}  
            @else 
             {{Form::open(['method'=>'delete','action'=>
            ['UsersController@restoreUser',$user->id]])}}
                <button type="submit">Re-activate</button>
            {{Form::close()}}  
            @endif
```

and in my Controller:

```
public function softDeleteUser($id){
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->delete();
    // redirect
    return Redirect::to('/admin');
}

public function restoreUser($id) {
    User::find($id)->restore();        
    $user->save();
    Redirect::to("/admin");
}
```

In my routes:

```
Route::post('/admin/user/{resource}/delete', 
       array('as' => 'admin.user.delete', 'uses' 
       =>'UsersController@softDeleteUser'));
Route::post('/admin/user/{resource}/restore', 
      array('as' => 'admin.user.restore', 
     'uses' =>'UsersController@restoreUser'));
```

However I get this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you've set your two forms to use the PATCH and DELETE method but your routes are set to POST (`Route::post`).

You can either change the routes:

```
Route::patch('/admin/user/{resource}/delete', 
    array('as' => 'admin.user.delete', 'uses' 
    =>'UsersController@softDeleteUser'));
Route::delete('/admin/user/{resource}/restore', 
    array('as' => 'admin.user.restore', 
   'uses' =>'UsersController@restoreUser'));
```

Or remove the `method` in your forms (it will default to POST)

```
{{Form::open(['action'=> ['UsersController@softDeleteUser',$user->id]])}}
     <button type="submit">Suspend</button>
{{Form::close()}}
```

And

```
{{Form::open(['action'=> ['UsersController@restoreUser',$user->id]])}}
     <button type="submit">Re-activate</button>
{{Form::close()}}
```